# Packaging/Hosting Selenium scripts

Tags: selenium-rc

A certain test script of mine needs to be run by the "operations" team periodically. My script uses the following components -
1. TestNG
2. Excel (for the input specifications)
3. Selenium RC, ofcourse.

It currently runs in Eclipse. 
Is there a way I can package and host it in an, ideally, web accessible location, that folks in operations can click on and review results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing an Ant script controlling execution.